# Confusion over how to implement IEnumerable

Tags: c#, ienumerator

I am new to IEnumerable in C# and am confused when reading about how to implement it from multiple sources.
Here is what I have gathered so far:
(1) source 1: If a class implements IEnumerable, it must implement IEnumerator, which in turn must implement MoveNext, Reset methods too. This means I need have all of these in the class:

```cs
class Product : IEnumerable
{
...
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        { return new ProductEnumerator();}
    ...
}
class ProductEnumerator : IEnumerator
{
...
    public bool MoveNext()
    {...}
   
    public void Reset()
    {...}
```

(2) Source 2: I can just simply use the below code and it is valid.

```cs
class Product
{
   public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts() {return new List<Product>{...}}
}
```

(3) Source 3:
When implementing the GetEnumerator method:

```cs
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() 
{
    return (Enumerator) GetEnumerator();
}
```

My questions here:

1. Why in Source 2 are we not using the interface syntax in declaring a class.e.g. public class Product:IEnumerator?
2. Why is it in Source 2 we do not need to implement IEnumerator?
3. What does the syntax in Source 3 actually mean? Are we declaring a method here? If yes, why is it not following the syntax of public IEnumerator GetEnumerator(){..}?

I am really quite confused and thanks for shining some light.

Comment: _"If a class implements IEnumerable, it must implement IEnumerator"_ - that is not true.

Comment: You need to take a few steps back. IEnumerable and enumerators are infrastructure code, generally not user code. Unless you know you want to implement a new collection type or write a custom enumerator, you don't implement those interfaces yourself. Why would you want a "product" class to be enumerable? Don't you just want it to have a List<Something> property instead?

Comment: So you have `Product` class; what are you going to enumerate, please? Does `Product` consist of other (sub-)products?

Comment: First dig into 'Collection; topics. It basically explain IEmunrable, List, Array. That u will know when to use what. Then look into the topic interface. Refer to your first question. It's important to learn and understand this and you will find them very useful in the future.

Comment: @Dmitry there wasn't anything wrong with your answer! Just mention that OP shouldn't probably do this, but expose a collection property instead.

Comment: @CodeCaster: it may well be that exposing a collection (or enumeration) is a better choice here. We don't have enough information though (what, why in which way etc. should be enumerated), that's why I've just shown how can `IEnumerable<T>` be implemented leaving alone all other possibilities (exposing a collection `List<Product>`, interfacem say `IReadOnly<Product>` etc.).

Comment: Implementing IEnumerable ws something we had to do before .NET 2.0 provided generics. If you wanted a strongly-typed collection you had to create one. It's been 17 years (?) or so since then. Now there so many collection types to meet every need that we never implement this ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

When we want to enumerate anything, we usually start from `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is the type of items we want to enumerate.
Assuming that you have `Product` which can contain (sub-) products in `List<Product> items`

```
class Product {
  ...
  private List<Product> items = new List<Product>(); 
  ...
}
```

you can put it as (please, note that there's `GetEnumerator` and no more methods)

```
// Note, that if class implements IEnumerable<T>
// it implements IEnumerable as well.
class Product : IEnumerable<Product> {
  ...
  private List<Product> items = new List<Product>(); 
  ...

  public IEnumerator<Product> GetEnumerator() {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  // Usually, it's nothing more than boiler plate code:
  // Having typed GetEnumerator (above) we return typeless
  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Now we should implement `IEnumerator<Product> GetEnumerator()` method. We have two main options here:
use the collection:

```
  ...
  // We want to enumerate items: let .Net do it for us
  public IEnumerator<Product> GetEnumerator() => items.GetEnumerator();
  ...
```

or some Linq query, e.g.

```
  ...
  // We want to enumerate items: let .Net do it for us
  public IEnumerator<Product> GetEnumerator() => items
    .Where(item => item.Name is not null) // Some condition here
    .GetEnumerator();
  ...
```

Another possibility is to implement custom enumeration and then call it via `GetEnumerator()`:

```
  private Product MyEnumeration() {
    foreach (var item in items) {
      yield return item;
    }
  }

  public IEnumerator<Product> GetEnumerator() => MyEnumeration().GetEnumerator();
```

Comment: The question remains why OP wants to do this. `foreach (var p in product) { ... }` is not idiomatic C#, we just do `foreach (var p in product.Items) { ... }`...